# Singleton and my db class

Tags: php, mysqli, singleton, undefined

When i try to open my site i getting this errors:

> Notice: Undefined property: User::$mysqli in \www\classes\db.class.php on line 75

---

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in www\classes\db.class.php on line 75

**75 line and GetInstance()**

```
public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (empty(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function session_check($username, $hash)
    {

        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT  `hash` FROM `accounts` WHERE `username` = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($db_hash);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            if ($hash == $db_hash) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**User class**

```
        class User extends db
    {
        public $username;
        public $user_info;
        public function  __construct()
        {
            if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || !isset($_SESSION['hash']) || !isset($_SESSION['last_activity'])) {
                Template::login_page('login.tpl');
                exit;
            } else {
                $this->username = $_SESSION['username'];
                if (!db::getInstance()->session_check($this->username, $_SESSION['hash'])) {
                    Template::login_page('login.tpl');
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

So, i have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: We also have no idea what's wrong, due to the absent db class code and usage context.

Comment: About the only thing we can say for sure is that `$this->mysqli` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @mario Just added the full code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use

> if (db::getInstance()->session_check($this->username,
>   $_SESSION['hash']))

instead of

> if (!db::getInstance()->session_check($this->username,
>   $_SESSION['hash']))

So, in case if class can be initialized(script connected to database) -> you can do something. In other case you need to throw exception "Can't connect to database.".

```
if (!db::getInstance()->session_check($this->username, $_SESSION['hash'])) {
    throw new Exception("Can't connect to database.");
} else {
    //blablabla
}
```